# Where do Eclipse sub-processes (launched with the "run" menu) show up?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.4

I'm using Eclipse 3.4.1, moving my first steps. When I run my project (a server process) a console opens. But for some reasons after a while I can't find it anymore (even if the process is still up). I'd like to find it to be able to see its output and/or kill it.
Is there a place in Eclipse where I can find all running sub-processes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a small button that looks like a monitor in the console panel. It lists all open consoles.
I'm ashamed I didn't find it myself before posting the question, but maybe it will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about "eclipse console", there is only one "console view", but several console instances.

You can browse the different consoles by clicking on the second button from the left in the console view (the one looking like a monitor)

Your console may 'disappear' because another message is displayed in the main console (stdout) process, while your server still runs with the other console instance.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way if you are dealing with lots of processes is to use the Debug view (note: NOT the debug perspective, just the debug 'view' or 'window').

It shows a list of running processes, including processes started with Run instead of Debug.  Selecting a process in the Debug view will open the corresponding Console, and visa-versa.

I put the Debug view above the Console view and size it to show just a few lines.